# Can I copy an ENTIRE Excel sheet and paste to another Excel spreadsheet using Power Automate. (Sharepoint)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, power-automate, excel-online

I am working from SharePoint.

I would like to COPY AN ENTIRE Excel Sheet-A from Spreadsheet A and Paste it into another Sheet, Sheet-B on Spreadsheet B using Microsoft Power Automate.

Some important things to note:

1. Sheet-A does not have column names (I know).
2. There are no Key values or Key Columns. Just random information.

Is there a way to go about this?

Comment: Can you edit the question and share us the flow you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately PowerAutomate really wants you to have your information in a table if you want to move or manipulate the data and wouldn't it be so useful to have a "Duplicate Sheet" function and copy n paste of individual cells.

If your sheet with the random data happened to be in a single large table, then this may work by apply to each item when navigating the underlying table.